# Ajax.ActionLink calling controller twice

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

When I click on  Ajax.ActionLink it is calling my controller twice.

```
<td id = @tdTag>
   @Ajax.ActionLink("LL-" + item.getProjectAbbreviation(item.projectID.Value) + "-" + item.prjLessonID, "Details",
                    new { id = item.lessonID },
                    new AjaxOptions
                        {
                          HttpMethod = "POST",
                          UpdateTargetId = "details",
                          InsertionMode = InsertionMode.InsertAfter ,
                          OnSuccess = "showDetails()"

                         })
```

My Controller looks like this...

```
   public ActionResult Details(int id)
    {
        using (LLDataContext storeDB = new LLDataContext())
        {
            var lesson = (from l in storeDB.lessons
                          where l.lessonID == id
                          select l).SingleOrDefault();

            return PartialView(lesson);

        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you provide the implementation of javascript method showDetails?

Answer (score 33):

I just ran in this same issue and I found that I had "jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js" loaded twice. I removed the second instance and all is working well. To see this in action, just add it three times and create an @Ajax.ActionLink(...) with an Confirm AjaxOption. You will get confirmed multiple times.

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your solution, save me lots of time.

Comment: Yep, that was the issue! (In my case, an ajax update to the page was reincluding that js file each time the update ran. Moved the include to outside the html returned by that ajax call and the issue went away.)

Comment: If you use bundles, and you have included validation with the following code:  bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive*","~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));
It might cause the similar behavior, specify the js without the *

Comment: Super, saved a lot time !, yes it was loaded two times and now issue is gone !....

Comment: @anAgent It doesn't solve my problem but it gives me hint to solve my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

use either of only one js not both one

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js")"></script>
```

or

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")"></script>
```

It will solve your problems.

Answer (score 1):

anAgent's answer helped me fix this problem, but as an add-on I will mention that, in my case, the multiple references to "jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js" were in different files; one was in myView.cshtml, and the other was in _Layout.cshtml.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have included the jquery unobtrusive script to your page (in addition to jquery):

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

and that you have enabled unobtrusive javascript in your web.config

```
<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
```

Also to further diagnose such problems I would recommend you using some tool which would allow you to see exactly what happens at the HTTP level. [FireBug](http://getfirebug.com/) is more than excellent for this kind of analysis. It will also show any possible javascript errors that you might have, it will show or not AJAX requests which will provide you with further information whether an AJAX request is performed or a normal request, ... useful stuff.

Comment: @crocaduck81, do you see the AJAX request sent in FireBug?

Comment: I do, it is sending the request twice.

Answer (score 0):

just check this jquery reference

```
src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"
```

may be you add in view twice 
or

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
    "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive*",
```