# Ajax.ActionLink making two requests

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Sales file", "Product", "Import", null, new AjaxOptions{ LoadingElementId = "spinner"}, new {@class="import"})
```

Its making two requests. One has the following on the query string...

> ?X-Requested-With=XMLHttpRequest /Import

I have looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6244411/ajax-actionlink-calling-controller-twice) but I'm sure that I only have one reference to ajax.unobtrusive in the page.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that you have some other javascript file included in your page which is AJAXifying all links. Something along the lines of:

```
$('a').click(function() {
    $.get(this.href, function(result) {

    });
    return false;
});
```

So you get 2 AJAX calls - one as a result of the `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js` script and the other as a result of your custom script.

Look at all the scripts that are included in your view and start removing them one by one until you find the smoking gun.