# I'm trying to change button text by calling action method using ajax.actionlink. That method is returning a string as button ID in new page

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

> LAYOUT:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/bootstrap")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
    <link rel="Stylesheet" href="../../Content/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="Stylesheet" href="../../Content/bootstrap-theme.min.css" />
</head>
@*<body style="background-image: url(../../Content/Images/old-paper.jpg)">*@
<body style="background-color: #EEE">
    @*---- WEB PAGE ---- *@
    <div class="wrap-middle">
        @*---- TITLE OF THE WEBSITE ----*@
        <div class="container-fluid" style="width: 100%; background-image: url('/Content/Images/Header.bmp')">
            <div>
                <h1>
                    ONLINE VOTING SYSTEM</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
        @*---- BODY SECTION ----*@
        <div class="jumbotron">
            <div class="container">
                @RenderBody()
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-bottom" style="box-shadow: 0 0 20px black;">
            <div class="container-fluid" style="color: Yellow">
                Copyright <sup><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-copyright-mark"></span></sup>2014.
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

> VIEW:

```
@model IEnumerable<Online_Voting_System_site.DAL.tbl_candidate>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "CandidateApproval";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

@Ajax.ActionLink("Approve",
                 "ApproveCandidate",
                 new { _CandidateID = item.CandidateID },
                 new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = item.CandidateID.ToString() }, 
                 new { @id = item.CandidateID.ToString(), @class = "btn btn-sm btn-success" })
```

> ACTION METHOD:

```
   public string ApproveVoter(string ID)
    {
       /* Logic is hidden.I use that ID parameter in here */

       return "Approved";    
    }
```

> I'm trying to change button text by calling action method using
>   ajax.actionlink. That action method is returning a string as button ID
>   but it displayed in new page.

Edit: The string should the text of the button. But the text is getting displayed in a new page.

Comment: is that button already on page?

Comment: is ``jquery-unobtrusive.js`` is included in you ``_layout.cshtml`` .can you show the html of that button?

Comment: @EhsanSajjad: I update my question.. check it

Comment: inspect html in firebug is jquery-unobtrusive-ajax is in the html?

Comment: @EhsanSajjad: That problem is cleared but now have another problem. When I click that button that action method is calling two times.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6244411/ajax-actionlink-calling-controller-twice

Comment: you have included unobtrusive ajax twice on page i suspect and you can see this post i referred